# What does a minus sign inside of dollar brackets of a shell script mean?

Tags: bash, shell-scripting

In an existing shell script, I'm seeing some variables referenced that either include or end with a minus sign.  For example:

```
PID=${PID-/run/unicorn.pid}
```

and:

```
run_by_init() {
    ([ "${previous-}" ] && [ "${runlevel-}" ]) || [ "${runlevel-}" = S ]
}
```

What do the minus signs mean in both of these scenarios?

Comment: Are you sure you copied and pasted exactly as they appear in the script?

Comment: Yes, of course I did.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the section on "Parameter Expansion" in the bash man page, this means "use the default value if the parameter is unset."  So for example,

```
${PID-/run/unicorn.pid}
```

equals $PID if $PID is set, otherwise /run/unicorn.pid.

Comment: Why does the second example include minus signs with no default value then? Am I missing something there?

Comment: No good reason I can see.  If, say, $runlevel is unset, then `${runlevel-}` substitutes an empty value for it.  But just `$runlevel` automatically does the same thing, so no, I don't see any reason to write it that way.

Comment: Thanks, I think that was my biggest source of confusion in looking at this!

Answer (score 10):

It should be emphasized that this means an **unset** variable. Not an empty one.
And to put to comparison with `:-`, which will use default value (the one after minus sign) if variable is **unset or null** (as in empty string).
Minus without a colon is not seen as often (at least not by me) and has more specific use than `:-` It's not even mentioned on [GNU manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) and not in my `man bash`, but it's described for example [on tldp](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html).

In cases where you need to substitute default value, when the variable doesn't hold sensible value. The later is more suitable.

`PID=${PID-/run/unicorn.pid}`
PID might have been used and later emptied using PID="" in the script. This association will than fail and PID will stay an empty string ""

`PID=${PID:-/run/unicorn.pid}`
PID will become "/run/unicorn.pid" if it was unset, but even if it was null ("") before.

A construct without a default value `${previous-}` is debated to be a safe-guard against someone having `set -u`

> set -u|nounset
>
> Treat unset variables and parameters other than the special parameters ‘@’ or ‘*’
>     as an error when performing parameter expansion.
>     An error message will be written to the standard error, and a
>     non-interactive shell will exit.
>   https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html

```
set -u
[ "${previous}" ] || echo "This will fail"
[ "${previous-}" ] || echo "This works"
```